# How to curve start of rectangle like a C shaped?

Tags: android, xml

Following is the required output

[image]

Following is what i am getting

[image]

As you can see i am getting a gap between first button's end and second button's start

Here is my code

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_activity_admin_login_apply_now"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/applynow"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/apply_now"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_activity_admin_login_check_status"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_activity_admin_login_check_status"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/checkstatus"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/check_status"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_activity_admin_login_apply_now"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_activity_admin_login_apply_now"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_activity_admin_login_apply_now" />
```

applynow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#6ECAF9"
        android:startColor="#049CE8" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp" />
</shape>
```

checkstatus.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#1981C2"
        android:startColor="#006CAF" />
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
        android:topRightRadius="3dp"
        />
    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp" />
</shape>
```

How to curve the start of second button toward the inner side so that there is no gap between first and second button?

Comment: What about overlapping the 2 buttons to reduce complexity ?

Comment: @Bruno How will overlapping solve the problem? How to overlap in constraintlayout?

Comment: if your 'Apply' button was 10 dp (or something like this) further to the right, you will have the illusion that the second button is curved

Comment: I am applying horizontal chain of ConstraintLayout so its not possible to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to make the main container RelativeLayout and give the RelativeLayout the main background that you have with dark blue,
and inside that RelativeLayout you put your textview on left

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making the second button curve inside, it would look good if you apply the curve on the first button only on the starting(i.e., on the left side), then apply curve on the second button in right side as in below sample code, now there will be no gap between and the button will be in sync.

applynow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:endColor="#6ECAF9"
            android:startColor="#049CE8" />
        <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        />
        <padding
            android:bottom="10dp"
            android:left="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:top="10dp" />
    </shape>
```

checkstatus.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#1981C2"
        android:startColor="#006CAF" />
    <corners
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        />
    <padding
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp" />
</shape>
```